# What type of Object does publishCreate accept?

Tags: mongodb, socket.io, sails.js, sails-mongo

When I use:

```
User.publishCreate(user.id);
```

My server logs:

```
error: Invalid usage of publishCreate() :: Values must have an `id`, instead got :: '54fc5ebf4da88b7260445f7d'
```

My data is being stored in MongoDB that creates an ObjectID. If I use user.id, it is supposed to pass the ObjectID.toString(), but that is not what my publishCreate method takes.

Comment: Docs for `publishCreate` are [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/publishCreate.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "id" as attributes, Waterline add you an id automatically or pass it like this
`User.publishCreate({id:newGuy.id,name:newGuy.name});`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/publishCreate.html), `publishCreate` method expects an object, and you are passing in a scalar value.  Ideally, you just pass in a newly-created `User` object, but if you want to restrict what gets sent you can construct the object yourself as in @dkx22's example.